# Inserting current date in database along with test score

Tags: php, mysql, date

**Note:** *I tried Google and "Questions that may already have your answer," but most results focus on inserting dates directly into a database table or emphasize software programs I'm not familiar with (e.g. sqlite).*

I'm using the script below to insert test ID's and scores into a database table. The data is submitted automatically after a user chooses the answers and clicks the Submit button.

```
try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO g1_test_scores (Test_Score, Test_ID) VALUES  (:Test_Score, :Test_ID)";
 $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $query->bindParam(':Test_ID', $Test_ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->bindParam(':Test_Score', $Test_Score, PDO::PARAM_STR); // varname?
// $query->bindParam(':Test_Score', $_POST['Test_Score'], PDO::PARAM_STR); // varname?
 $query->execute();
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'PDOException : '.  $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'd just like to know how to insert the current date (the user's date) at the same time. I have a column/field in my database table named Test_Date, and it's in the date format; the default display is 0000-00-00.

If a user takes a test three times on Jan. 1, 2016, then the same date would be recorded in each of the resulting three rows. If they take the same test again the next day, then 2016-01-02 would be recorded in that row.

Comment: is the server date, the same as the user date ?

Comment: Are you using sqlite, mysql or what are you using? In MySQL you can define a standard value for new records. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html Alternative you can use PHPs time() function and send the return value to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that field already, then this code should do the job:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO g1_test_scores (Test_Score, Test_ID, Test_Date) VALUES  (:Test_Score, :Test_ID, date())";
```